# how to compute logarithms in Python not using math.log

Tags: python, logarithm

in a while loop of a code of mine the while breaks because

```
>>> 3<=abs(math.log(1000,10))
False
```

but, of course the log of 1000 in base 10 is exactly 3, so i was confident that the condition should work...

But in fact i have this:

```
>>> abs(math.log(1000,10))
2.9999999999999996
```

So i would like any suggestions: is there a "best practice" rounding the result or is there a smarter method to compute logarithms?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe use numpy for that, I use it for a lot of stuff, not too sure how it handles logarithms. You could give it a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For base 10 you should use:

```
math.log10(x)
```

It returns the base-10 logarithm of x. This is usually more accurate than log(x, 10).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use a tolerance to account for the computational errors. Something like this for example (you can tune the power of 10 you want depending on the required accuracy)

```
abs(math.log(1000,10))-3 >= -1e-6
```

Using numpy I also have `np.log10(1000) = 3.0`. You could use this as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing *float numeric imprecision* in action, which is a fundamental limitation of computing systems you cannot entirely circumvent. Two standard practices are: (1) increasing numeric precision (e.g. `float64`), or (2) comparison by threshold:

1. You can use [Numpy](https://numpy.org/), which runs on `float64` by default, and is the fastest Python library for numeric computing (even faster than C)
2. *Ex*: `abs(math.log(1000,10) - eps)`, where `eps` (epsilon) is some small number (e.g. `1e-7`)

In fact, Numpy has a handy method just for this, if comparing multiple values at once (vectors, matrices): [`np.allclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html). To compare as in (2), set `rtol=0`, and just use `atol`; example:

```
vec1 = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])
vec2 = np.array([.33, .33, .33, .33])
print(np.allclose(vec1/3, vec2, rtol=0, atol=0.01))  # True
print(np.allclose(vec1/3, vec2, rtol=0, atol=0.001)) # False
```

---

**How to see true values**: `(1e-5 + 1e-5 + 1.) == 1.00002` will show `True`, but it *isn't*; Python automatically simplifies the console-logged representation for you. To see the actual numeric value, use Python's `format`:

```py
print(format(1e-5 + 1e-5 + 1., '.32f'))
# print(format(1e-5 + 1e-5 + 1., '.32f'))
1.00001999999999990897947554913117
```

^ this is the true value stored in memory, and it's what `1.00002` is converted to before running `==`, which is why it shows `True`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) to check is a value is close to another value.

```
import math

print(math.isclose(3,math.log(1000,10)))
```

You can change your condition like this

```
logvalue = math.log(1000,10)
print(3 <= logvalue or math.isclose(3,logvalue))
```

And get `True` as output